# How to get name property out of the result of eigenvalue in igraph?

Tags: python, social-networking, igraph

I import a list of edges to igraph.

The data looks like this.

```
393795446 18215973
393795446 582203919
393795446 190709835
393795446 1093090866
393795446 157780872
393795446 1580109739
393795446 3301748909
393795446 1536791610
393795446 106170345
393795446 9409752
```

Which is something (source, target) of twitter followers.

I imported by running this code.

```
from igraph import *
import timeit
twitter_igraph = Graph.Read_Ncol('twitter_edgelist.txt', directed=True)
print twitter_igraph.summary()

IGRAPH DN-- 2869228 6764984 -- 
+ attr: name (v)
```

The import is completed and I can get any vertex back by `twitter_igraph.vs.find(name='393795446')`

However, when I run eigenvalue calculation it returns just a list of all the vertexes which I'm not sure how to reverse lookup to get the twitter id.

```
start = timeit.default_timer()
igraph_eg = twitter_igraph.evcent()
stop = timeit.default_timer()
print 'It takes {} seconds to finish'.format(stop - start)


igraph_eg.sort(reverse=True)
print igraph_eg[:10]
```

after I sort `igraph_eg` I can get the top 10 eigen value but I would like to show `name` property of that vertex. How do I print the name of the vertex with eigen value?

This is my workaround

```
np_vals = numpy.array(igraph_eg)
sorted_eigen = numpy.argsort(np_vals)[::-1][:20]

for eg in sorted_eigen:
    print twitter_igraph.vs.find(eg)['name']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
ids = sorted(range(g.vcount()), key=igraph_eg.__getitem__, reverse=True)
names = g.vs[ids]["name"]
```

This will give you the IDs of the vertices in order of decreasing eigenvector centrality. However, since you are most likely interested only in the top few vertices, a partial sort using heaps might be faster:

```
from heapq import nlargest
ids = nlargest(10, xrange(g.vcount()), key=igraph_eg.__getitem__)
names = g.vs[ids]["name"]
```

This is for Python 2.x; if you are on Python 3.x, use `range` instead of `xrange`.

For what it's worth, your NumPy-based solution with `argsort` is equally good, so you could also use `sorted_eigen` from there as follows:

```
names = g.vs[sorted_eigen]["name"]
```

Note that you can plug a vertex index vector straight into `g.vs[]` to get a subset of vertices with those IDs.

Answer (score 0):

This is by no means the best solution but it works. Keep in mind that it will only return a single node id, even when multiple nodes share the same eigenvector centrality score.

```
def eigenID(ev, graph):
    '''
    ev - eigenvector centrality value that you're locating
    graph - the graph object that you're looking in
    '''

    g = graph
    evs = g.evcent()
    ids = g.vs['name']

    ev_index = evs.index(ev)
    node_id = ids[ev_index]

    return node_id
```

I can refine this later on if it's not helpful.

Let me know.